# error with writelines(), when creating json objects

Tags: python, json

I wnat to convert the text file into json objects, and my inputfile i.e. text file has large number of objects(4 mb). It throw an error when I try to write the json objects into text file. Here is the error"writelines( ) argument must be a sequence of strings". Here is my input file:

created_at : 03 Ekim 2014 Cuma, 06:36, article : İSTANBUL (CİHAN)- Fethullah Gülen Hocaefendi'nin “421. Nağme: Şamatalarınız Haramîliğinizi Örtemeyecek!..” isimli yeni sohbeti, herkul.org sitesinde yayınlandı. Hocaefendi, "Şamatayla hangi şirretliği kapamak istediğini herkes anlıyor. Silinmez o zihinlerden" ifadelerini kullandı.Sohbetinde Allah Rasûlü (sallallâhu aleyhi ve sellem) Efendimiz’in, “Allahım beni kendi gözümde küçük, insanlar nazarında ise (yüklediğin misyona uygun.
created_at : 06 Ekim 2014 Pazartesi, 11:57, article : KAYSERİ (CİHAN)- Kimse Yok Mu Derneği Kayseri Şubesi, hayırseverlerin bağışlarıyla paket haline getirdiği kurban etlerini ihtiyaç sahiplerine ulaştırdı. Şehirde daha önce derneğe müracaatta bulunan ve tespit edilen aileler için şehrin 4 ayrı noktasında kurban eti dağıtım merkezi oluşturuldu. Kurban etlerini alan aileler ise Kimse Yok Mu ile yüzlerinin güldüğünü ve emeği geçenlere teşekkür ettiklerini söylediler. Geçen yıla göre ise bağış miktarlarının yüzde 50 oranında arttığı bildirildi. Kimse Yok Mu Derneği’nin Kayseri Şubesi’nde Kurban Bayramı nedeniyle hareketlilik yaşanıyor. Dernek, hayırseverlerin bağışladığı kurbanların kesimi yapıldıktan sonra. Here is my code:

```
    #!usr/bin/python
import sys, os
import json
inputfile = open('bugun_data_collection_KimseYokmu.txt', 'r')
outputfile = open('bugun_data_collection_json_KimseYokmu.txt', 'w') 
#shows how the dictionary looks like
reps = {"created_at": "date","article": "text"}
#reads the input file line by line
for line in inputfile:
    outputfile.writelines((line, json.dumps(reps))
inputfile.close() 
outputfile.close()
```

this is the error: "" line 11
    inputfile.close() 
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Notice the error message: `"writelines( ) argument must be a sequence of strings"`. It's throw out because the second element of the parameter(tuple type) is a `dict` not a string as expected. You can use `json.dumps(reps)` to convert it to string, like this:

```
outputfile.writelines((line, json.dumps(reps)))
```

Besides, you have put the file close operation in the `for` loop, this will cause another error when you write into or read from a closed file.

If you want to extract text from the input file, you can do it like this(did not deal with exceptions):

```
#reads the input file line by line
outputlines = []
for line in inputfile:
    text = line.split('article : ')[1]
    date = line.split('article : ')[0].split('created_at : ')[1]
    reps = {"created_at": date,"article": text}
    outputlines.append(json.dumps(reps))
outputfile.writelines(outputlines)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have changed the code according to you also with closed file out of loop, though it gives me error as "invalid syntax" in that inputfile.close() line

Comment: @swethaprasad paste the latest code and error message.

Comment: @swethaprasad You missed a `)` at the end of line `outputfile.writelines(...`.

Comment: @ WKPlus : thanks for the correction, but it just creates a json file with {"article": "text", "created_at": "date"} and all the text and the date, but this is what I was aiming for {"created_at" : "03 Ekim 2014 Cuma, 06:36", "article" : "İSTANBUL (CİHAN)- Fethullah Gülen Hocaefendi'nin “421. Nağme: Şamatalarınız Haramîliğinizi Örtemeyecek!..” isimli yeni sohbeti, herkul.org sitesinde yayınlandı. Hocaefendi, "Şamatayla hangi şirretliği kapamak ist...." }

Comment: @swethaprasad update the answer. BTW, sof is not a place for asking for code.